# I'm trying to display a custom post type generated by a wordpress plugin (twitter tools)

Tags: twitter, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using this plugin to load tweets onto a website:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/twitter-tools/

It does a nice job of putting together a sidebar widget, but I'm trying to work out a method to display the posts in a loop so that I can echo individual posts on a page. (kind of like blog entries in a list)

The site it confidential, but I'll do my best to share examples and un-branded code.

The plugin is installed, along with it's requirements, and it's loading tweets just fine:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdWoe.png

This is sort of how I'd like to load in these posts, but it's not working:

```
<? $tweet = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'tweet', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
    while ( $tweet->have_posts() ) : $tweet->the_post();
    $info = twitter_post(); ?>

    <div class="item twitter-item">
        ECHO TWEET ARRAY HERE (specifically: date, post, author, time)
</div>

<? endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This code is wrong, but I'm not entirely sure how to make it right. I know the twitter_post(); bit isn't right...

Any time I try to echo something out of 'post_type => 'tweet', I get NULL. I think I'd be in business if I could just get a var_dump() to work.

If anyone can take a look and offer advice, I'd appreciate it.

Note: I'm not obligated to use twitter tools if there's a better method to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had help from a friend and managed to solve it with this code:

```
<? $twitter = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'aktt_tweet', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); while ( $twitter->have_posts() ) : $twitter->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="twitter-item">
        <? the_content(); ?>
        <div class="author"><?= $post->tweet->data->user->screen_name ?></div>
        <div class="meta"><?= human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'),current_time('timestamp')) . ' ago'; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<? endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

For clarification: the post type was 'aktt_tweet', not 'tweet'

Once I had that working, I was able to run the information through a loop and output the data with the_content() and calls to the database like this:

```
$post->tweet->data->user->~item_in_database~
```